# Xamarin forms content page issue

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I'm having some issues adding a new content page. I think it's some kind of issue with Visual Studio 2017 Community. When I add a new content page I can't see the .xaml file. After clicking show all files I see this:

[image: Visual Studio solution]

Also, I can't include the .xaml file in the project. When I click include in project nothing happens. I'm using visual studio 2017 community, Windows 10.

What should I do?

Comment: Does it work on a different project? This is very hard to figure out what you actually did, I would suggest you do the steps of how you add a content page.

Comment: no, it does not work, i created a new project and the same issue

Comment: Had this exact issue at first. I fixed it manually by editing the xml in project file. However, after upgrading my version of Visual Studio it seemed to resolve itself going forward. I'm on 15.5.2

Also, I seem to remember this being helpful: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/100129/xamarin-forms-vs2017-netstandard-xaml-and-code-behind-are-not-grouped

Comment: After another visual studio update it started working, @maplemale please post your coment as an answer to select you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it manually by editing the xml in project file and closing / opening the project. However, after upgrading my version of Visual Studio it seemed to resolve itself going forward.

I'm on 15.5.2 Also, I seem to remember this being related:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=55591

...and suggestions here being helpful:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/100129/xamarin-forms-vs2017-netstandard-xaml-and-code-behind-are-not-grouped